# Showing empty graph in tkinter until you click the button

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to make GUI app that draws the graph when a button is pressed. I want to have an empty graph on tkinter window, and when you press the button named "Draw", the program should draw the graph.

I made a window that shows the empty graph, and button for drawing, but when button is pressed, nothing happens, and I do not get any error. Can you help me with this?

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title("Cost Analysis")                         
myApp.geometry("1900x1000")

X=[1,4,6,8,9]
Y=[3,5,7,8,10]

fprojektiTroskovi=Figure(figsize=(7, 4.5),dpi=83)
GrafikProjektiTroskovi=fprojektiTroskovi.add_subplot(111)

CanvasProjectsTroskovi=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fprojektiTroskovi, master=myApp)
CanvasProjectsTroskovi.show()
CanvasProjectsTroskovi.get_tk_widget().grid(row=30,column=0,sticky="wn",padx=5)

toolbar_FrameProjektiTroskovi=Frame(myApp)
toolbar_FrameProjektiTroskovi.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="wn",padx=5)

ToolbarProjectsTroskovi = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(CanvasProjectsTroskovi,toolbar_FrameProjektiTroskovi)
ToolbarProjectsTroskovi.update()
CanvasProjectsTroskovi._tkcanvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="wn",padx=5,pady=5)

GrafikProjektiTroskovi.set_xlabel("Size")
GrafikProjektiTroskovi.set_ylabel("Costs")
GrafikProjektiTroskovi.set_title("All Projects (Size - Costs)")
GrafikProjektiTroskovi.grid()


def draw_graph():

    GrafikProjektiTroskovi.plot(X, Y, color="blue",marker="o", linewidth=1, label="Planned Costs")

    GrafikProjektiTroskovi.legend()

button=Button(myApp, text="Draw", command=draw_graph)
button.grid(row=0,column=1)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to use `人物油画.draw_idle()`

Comment: Add `CanvasProjectsTroskovi.show()` at the end of your function.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend !!!

You are the best !!!

Comment: The program works fine, only problem is, whenever I click the "Draw" button, i get another legend on the graph, so If I press the button 7 times, I will have the same legend 7 times.

Is there a way to fix this, how can I put only one legend, no matter how meny  times someone presses the buttton?